# Call a function when a child process finishes

Tags: c++, function, process

In my c++ program several child processes are started using fork and execv. I don't wait for them so they run in the background. When they finish running, I want to run a certain function. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `SIGCHLD` signal and call your function in the handler. Be careful what you call in the handler, you should only call **async-signal-safe** functions.

Comment: How do you know what those functions are?

Comment: @z-buffer: There is a list at the end of this page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you *do* want to wait for the processes to finish, but you want to run the processes in parallel rather than sequentially. If so, start each process as you do now, then use the `waitpid()` system call on each child pid. When every process has exited, every waitpid will have returned.

Comment: Not if you want to wait for the subprocesses to finish.

Comment: I don't want the parent process to wait for the child.